# Устройства с USB OTG в каком из устройств

Tags: usb

Для работы USB OTG оба устройства должны обладать поддержкой OTG  или достаточно одного устройства с поддержкой OTG.
К примеру телефон и к нему можно любую флешку подтыкнуть или камеру или клаву?
И в догонку. Если два устройства не обладают OTG но их подключить к друг другу с возможно ли через AT команды наладить связь между ними?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на первый вопроц тебе уже ответили, но тут офф доки:
http://www.usb.org/developers/onthego/USB_OTG_Intro.pdf

а на вдогонку, можешь на досуге почитать, тут более-менее полный вайтпапер по USB OTG
http://www.usb.org/developers/onthego/OTG3andEH_Compliance_Plan_1.0.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Лучше почитать на [wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#USB_OTG).
В большинстве случаев достаточно одного устройства с поддержкой OTG. Главное, чтобы драйвера были у ведущего устройства.

> К примеру телефон и к нему можно любую флешку подтыкнуть или камеру или клаву?

Флешку, клавиатуру - да. Камеру - смотря какую, если ПК видит эту камеру без дополнительных драйверов и программ, то и телефон обычно видит, открывая Галерею.

По второму вопросу, как именно Вы их подключите?

Comment: USB OTG кабелем. один USB второй мини USB

Comment: Если ведущий поддерживает OTG, то будет работать. А если оба не поддерживают, то уже нет.

Comment: Вообще не возможно или все таки есть возможность через одно устройство давать команды другому и получать из него данные??? Возможно все это можно сделать на низком уровне?